# i am trying to store list item on click event using java script and acces it to another page for sql query, but i cant

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#licity li").click(function () {
         alert($(this).text());
         document.getElementById('<%= Session["licitys"] %>') = $(this).text();             
     });
 });     
</script>
```

another page cs code:

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select name,number,city_name,dic_name from ab_db.dic where dic_name=@dicnamep and city_name='satara'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dicnamep",MySqlDbType.String);
    cmd.Parameters["@dicnamep"].Value = Session["dicname"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@licityp", MySqlDbType.String);
    cmd.Parameters["@licityp"].Value = Session["licitys"];
    GlobalClass.adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    MySqlCommandBuilder bui = new MySqlCommandBuilder(GlobalClass.adap);
    GlobalClass.dt = new DataTable();
    GlobalClass.adap.Fill(GlobalClass.dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = GlobalClass.dt;

    GridView1.DataBind();
```

First session id working properly but another which was accepted using java script not working properly. Please give suggestions.

Comment: Where have you put the cs code? Inside a server-side `click` hopefully?

Comment: No.  This coding in page load of dictionary output page

Comment: OK. So you want to the user click on an `li` in the client-side, then run that query based on what the user has clicked?

Comment: yes. after click text i.e 'licitys' is sent to sql query

Comment: OK. This won't work. Let me tell you what to do

Comment: Ok. Tell me what i need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was solved by using cookies. thanks for help.

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
     var d = new Date();
     d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
     var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
     document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#licity li").click(function () {
         setCookie("city", $(this).text().toString(),30);
         alert("You selected:"+$(this).text());
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify ur javascript code as :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#licity li").click(function () {
     alert($(this).text());
     document.getElementById('<%= Session["licitys"] %>').value = $(this).text();             
 });
});
```

You haven't put ".value" in document.getElementbyId just correct it..

Comment: change the code as you say but didn't  got accepted result. is there any way?

Comment: i just checked ur code and find a mistake and post answer @AkshayKhade ...my ans is correct but if ur problem persists..in ur current problem just take a hidden field instead and put its id in document.getElementById and get that hidden field field value on post instead of taking a session...

Comment: okk just try i m giving u this suggestion of taking hidden field instead because it is not a good practice to use too many sessions in a application...Good Luck..

Comment: i used '<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1"  runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>' control and stored clicked list item value but cant access in other .cs page

Comment: use this document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value= $(this).text();   in document.ready in javascript..it will work ...